# Removing boilerplate logging setup

Tags: python-2.7, logging, python-decorators

I'm seeing this very common code I'm using to setup logging.

```
 def has_host_running(self):
        log = CustomLogger.action_logger(name=sys._getframe().f_code.co_name, **self.menvargs)
        result = self.bash_query.check_is_server_available(log)
        self.results[sys._getframe().f_code.co_name] = result
        log.debug('result: {}'.format(result))
        return result
```

Looking for dry way to implement this behavior.
Key is that I need to be able to reference/call a log statement from **within** the function and any child function calls.

******************************edit2*******************************

The most elegant sloppy solution I could get to work. 
Loosely adapted from: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Controllable_DIY_debug

## heavily based on https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Controllable_DIY_debug

class ActionLog:
    def **init**(self):
        pass

```
def __call__(self, f):
    log = self.get_actionlogger(name=f.func_name)

    def newf(log, *args, **kwds):
        # pre-function call actions:
        log.debug('Start.')
        log.debug('    info: params= {args}, {kwds}'.format(args=args, kwds=kwds))

        # function call
        f_result = f(log, *args, **kwds)

        # post-function call actions:
        log.debug('    info: result= {result}'.format(result=f_result))
        log.debug('Complete.')
        return f_result

    # changes to be made to returned function
    newf.__doc__ = f.__doc__
    return newf(log)

def get_actionlogger(self, name, **kwargs):
    import logging
    import ast
    from Helper import ConfigManager

    logname = 'action.{func_name}'.format(func_name=name)
    logger = logging.getLogger(logname)

    # value stored in ini file.
    # either DEBUG or ERROR right now.
    # todo: store actual logging_level
    # todo: store an array/dict for log_name in .ini
    #       this will allow multiple parameters to be stored within the single entry.
    #       ex:
    #       action.check_stuff:    logging_level=DEBUG,handler_stream=TRUE,handler_file=stuff.log,formatter='{name} - {message}
    conf_logging_level = ConfigManager('config.ini').get_section_dict('CustomLogging_Level').get(logname, 'DEBUG')
    logging_level = logging.DEBUG
    if conf_logging_level == 'DEBUG':
        logging_level = logging.DEBUG
    if conf_logging_level == 'ERROR':
        logging_level = logging.ERROR

    logger.setLevel(logging_level)

    # very hacky
    # while logging.getLogger is a singleton, adding the handler is not.
    # without this check, this code will result in duplicate handlers added.
    # currently will not edit/replace the existing handler.
    # currently will not allow another handler to be added after the first.
    # main issue here is that I can't figure out how to determine labels/names within logger.handlers
    # todo: properly label handler
    # todo: check for existing labels & types (file, stream, etc)
    if len(logger.handlers) == 0:
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        ch.setLevel(logging_level)
        ch.set_name = logname

        # create formatter
        formatter = logging.Formatter(' %(name)s - %(message)s')
        ch.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(ch)

    return logger
```

`@ActionLog()
def check_stuff(log, *args, **kwds):
    result = True
    log.debug('    info: text call from within function.')
    return result`

if check_stuff:
    print 'check_stuff is true.'

So it works with the one parameter "log" being passed into the class. does not work if the class does not have the log parameter. I'm not sure how to handle if there are further parameters... likely with *args or **kwargs, but this solution doesn't handle that.

Apologies on the code formatting... I can't seem to get the class decorator in the same block as the decorated func and func call.

*** v3.0 ***
v2 had a problem with multiple arguments. Solved that and streamlined v3 quite a bit.

```
def ActionLog(wrapped):
def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

    log = CustomLogger.action_logger(wrapped.func_name)
    newargs = list()
    for a in args:
        newargs.append(a)
    newargs.append(log)

    f = wrapped(*newargs, **kwargs)

    if f is None:
        f = ''
    else:
        f = '\tResult: {}'.format(f)

    log.debug('Complete.{}'.format(f))
    return f
return _wrapper
```

This works better and has replaced most of my boilerplate logging calls for actions that take a single argument.

Still having problems with named args vs kwargs. I'd like to just pass args through and add my custom items to kwargs, but that had a few issues.

Comment: Kind of have it. It works... but I'm sure isn't optimized or elegant.

Comment: okay, only works with static functions. Need to handle that first reference to **self** within a class function within the decorator. Not sure how to grab and pass that down along with log, args and kwargs.